# Compare dates to fill a cell using VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel, date

I'm trying to compare two dates with the format DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM AM/PM, the idea is that if one date is greater than the other it puts in a field the word "Before" or "After" if it's lower.

I've tried doing this but failed miserably.

```
For col = 0 To objSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    objSheet.Range("A2").Formula = "=IF(Value < B&(col+2), Before,After)"
Next
```

Line  `objSheet.Range("A2").Formula = "=IF(Value < B&(col+2), Before,After)"` seems to not throw any error but all I get in my excel file is `#NAME?`

Value is a string that contains the value to which the other string is going to be compared to. Example

```
' Value = 5/4/2016 8:00:00 PM
' Value in B column: 5/5/2016 12:00:00 PM
```

then the if should output = BEFORE but if

```
'Value in B column: 5/5/2016 2:00:00 AM
```

then the output should be AFTER

I've seen some diff_date function but it doesn't seem to be integrated because it doesn't show up as an option.

It's there a way to achieve this? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would use a different variable than Value as it is a reserved word in vba.  So lets use `vlue` then you formula would be: `"=IF(""" & Vlue & """ < B" & col + 2 & ", Before,After)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited** This works for me in Excel 2013, but I've had to make some assumptions about what you're doing.  The below code fills in column A depending on whether the date in `Value` is before or after the value in column B.

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 0

Public Sub PopulateDates()
    Dim dateString As String
    Dim row As Long
    dateString = "5/4/2016 8:00:00 PM"
    Dim dateRepresentation As String
    dateRepresentation = "VALUE(""" & dateString & """)"

    Dim newFormula As String
    For row = 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        newFormula = "=IF(" & dateRepresentation & " < B" & CStr(row) & ", ""Before"",""After"")"
        ActiveSheet.Cells(row, 1).Formula = newFormula
    Next row
End Sub
```

Lots going on here.

- `dateString` instead of `Value` per Scott Craner's note, and because `Value` is so generic you might forget what it means.
- `dateRepresentation` is a way to represent a date as a literal in a worksheet formula.  It is, e.g., `VALUE("5/4/2016 8:00 PM")`.
- `newFormula` is on its own line so you can check it in the debugger before you make the assignment. :)

  - the `row` (you had `col+2`) is part of your VBA, so it is not part of your formula.  `CStr(row)` makes a string (e.g., `42`), and then `&` pastes that string after `B` and before `,`.
- `ActiveSheet.Cells` instead of `ActiveSheet.Range` because the latter didn't work for me.  You would use `objSheet` instead of `ActiveSheet`

The result of all this is to put, e.g., in cell A1:

```
=IF(VALUE("5/4/2016 8:00:00 PM") < B1, "Before","After")
```

Comment: I only had to switch places after and before because I was getting the inverse result. But this worked!!! thank you very very much